# Is there a platform agnostic shell command to check for OS name?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have been working on a *vscode* extension update where a file needs to have its contents updated if it is a UNIX platform. 
I haven't yet been able to come up with a code that works both on bash and powershell. Any answer would greatly help.

Comment: I think your issue would be less about shell and more about the different operating systems themselves

Comment: We can't help you with Powershell on [unix.se]. I've voted to migrate your question to [so].

Comment: Why are you running a shell command before determining what the shell is? Why not check the OS in your extension's code? What language is your extension written in? It _is_ possible to write a program that prints `Windows` when it's run under Powershell and `Unix` when it's run under sh: the word you're looking for is *polyglot* and I'm sure there are Powershell-sh polyglots on the web. But it's unlikely that this is the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: There are **no even platform agnostic APIs to check for OS name**. If you're writing an application for some OS'es it may make sense to tell us what those OSes could be, so that we could go from there.